# What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a composition of two arbitrary linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector, vector-spaces

Let $S$ and $T$ be two linear transformations on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S$ and $T$. I am trying to find out the relation(s) among the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S$, $T$ and $S\circ T$. Is there any relation of this kind?

Comment: In gebera this seems hopeless. If they are normal and commutte, then easy. Do you know anything about your matrices?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai  excelent comment! An infinite dimensional analogy is that a commuting familly of  compact operators has a common invariant subspace.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai what do you mean by 'gebera', sorry?

Comment: I am guessing he meant 'general'.

Comment: @AndresBatkai I am considering general matrices.

Comment: Sorry,yes. Did not check what I was typing. I meant general.

Comment: For products of unitary matrices, there are inequalities relating the eigenvalues of the product with that of the factors, see https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9712013 .  For arbitrary matrices, there is not much one can say beyond what one can get from the determinant identity $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem, the relations are not equalities but inequalities,
and in an important special case it was solvedd in

S. Agnihotri and C. Woodward, Eigenvalues of products of unitary matrices and quantum
Schubert calculus, math.AG/9712013, Math. Res. Lett. 5 (1998), 817–836. MR 2000a:14066